# couldn't parse bundle asset chunk-vendors.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I created a project using vue ui. When I clicked the serve button, it's ended with an error. I can't open the app I have created. The error is:

```
Couldn't parse bundle asset "{path}\dist\js\chunk-vendors.js".
Analyzer will use module sizes from stats file.
```

Comment: Try this
```
npm install node-sass --save
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit `.vuerc` and change/update `"packageManager": "npm"`